# Excel VBA to Create Row Groups based on Multiple Criterias

Tags: excel, vba

**Input Data  will be in below format -**

```
+--------------------------------------+--------+---------+----------+
|                 Desc                 |  Doc   | Invoice |  Order   |
+--------------------------------------+--------+---------+----------+
| XXXXXXX;SFFFFFFFF;QQWEWEE;878dDDss11 |  98988 |   27891 | XXX32222 |
| XXXXXXX;SFFFFFFFF;QQWEWEE;878dDDss11 |  45444 |  422445 | #        |
| XXX32222                             |   4333 |   23444 | #        |
| #                                    |   4454 |    3345 | XXX32333 |
| #                                    |  32333 |   44222 | ddh33333 |
| XXX32333                             | 323222 |   45333 | #        |
| XXX32333                             | 322433 |   34333 | #        |
| 4454                                 |   3333 |  232222 | #        |
| XXXSDDD-ddh33333                     |  34433 |   45555 | XX344444 |
+--------------------------------------+--------+---------+----------+
```

i want a new column which can tell groups based on 2 criteria as below -

1. if same value in desc col, then row group will be same like group 1, group 2 etc
2. if order or doc or invoice column value is there in Desc column then row will belong to same group

Output will be -

```
+--------------------------------------+--------+---------+----------+----------+
|                 Desc                 |  Doc   | Invoice |  Order   | Grouping |
+--------------------------------------+--------+---------+----------+----------+
| XXXXXXX;SFFFFFFFF;QQWEWEE;878dDDss11 |  98988 |   27891 | XXX32222 | Group 1  |
| XXXXXXX;SFFFFFFFF;QQWEWEE;878dDDss11 |  45444 |  422445 | #        | Group 1  |
| XXX32222                             |   4333 |   23444 | #        | Group 1  |
| #                                    |   4454 |    3345 | XXX32333 | Group 2  |
| #                                    |  32333 |   44222 | ddh33333 | Group 3  |
| XXX32333                             | 323222 |   45333 | #        | Group 2  |
| XXX32333                             | 322433 |   34333 | #        | Group 2  |
| 4454                                 |   3333 |  232222 | #        | Group 2  |
| XXXSDDD-ddh33333                     |  34433 |   45555 | XX344444 | Group 3  |
+--------------------------------------+--------+---------+----------+----------+
```

so far i have tried writing below code

```
i = 0
For Each cell1 In Range("C5:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Cells
Debug.Print cell1.Row
jvno = cell1.Offset(0, 5).Value
invno = cell1.Offset(0, 6).Value
ordno = cell1.Offset(0, 7).Value
        For Each cell3 In Range("C5:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Cells
        Debug.Print cell3.Row
            If ((cell1.Value = cell3.Value) And cell1.Value <> "#") Or InStr(cell3.Value, jvno) > 0 Or InStr(cell3.Value, invno) > 0 Or (InStr(cell3.Value, ordno) > 0 And (Not IsEmpty(ordno)) And ordno <> "#") Then
                cell1.Offset(0, 18).Value = "Group " & i
                cell3.Offset(0, 18).Value = "Group " & i
            End If
        Next cell3
        i = i + 1
Next cell1
```

Comment: Edited the question with what i have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

If we suppose that Desc is in C and Doc, Invoice, Order are in H, I, J, and the groups are in U, 
I changed your code like this :

```
i = 1
Set cell1 = Range("C5")
repeat:
cell1.Offset(0, 18).Value = "Group " & i
    jvno = cell1.Offset(0, 5).Value
    invno = cell1.Offset(0, 6).Value
    ordno = cell1.Offset(0, 7).Value

    For Each cell3 In Range("C6:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Cells
        If ((cell1.Value = cell3.Value) And cell1.Value <> "#") Or InStr(cell3.Value, jvno) > 0 Or InStr(cell3.Value, invno) > 0 Or (InStr(cell3.Value, ordno) > 0 And (Not IsEmpty(ordno)) And ordno <> "#") Then
            If cell3.Offset(0, 18).Value = "" Then
                cell3.Offset(0, 18).Value = "Group " & i
            End If
        End If
    Next cell3
i = i + 1
Set cell4 = cell1.Offset(0, 18)
While cell4.Value <> ""
    Set cell4 = cell4.Offset(1, 0)
Wend
If cell4.Row <= Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row Then
    Set cell1 = Range("C" & cell4.Row)
    GoTo repeat
End If
```

So, I have the same group names like you, ine the column U.

Hope this help